# Angularjs alway blank element in select tag

Tags: javascript, select, view, angularjs, controller

I am new to Angular.js (and also to this Forum) and want to try out some basics, but I got stucked at working with select and options.

I have a small app and want to add a select-box, but I get a blank option which I want to get rid of.

I was searching here on Stackoverflow and, of course, Google, and tried out may options and hints, but nothing seems to work for me.

I hope someone can help me here...

About the app:
I have some Items with attribures like item.Name or item.Price etc. and want to store the value of the selected tag with item.Store.

This is part of the view:

```
<td>
<select ng-model="item.Store" ng-options="item.storeName for item in items.Stores">
</select></td>
```

And this is what I have in my controller:

```
$scope.items.Stores = [
    {storeId : 1, storeName : 'Spar' },      
    {storeId : 2, storeName : 'Billa' },
    {storeId : 3, storeName : 'Merkur' }, 
];
```

Amongst others I tried this one:

```
$scope.item.Store = $scope.items.Stores[1];
```

But I always get the error message: 
"$scope.item is undefined...."
although my ng-model is also named item.Store, so I assume there is a problem with the . or something like that...

Thanks for your help and if something relevant from the code is missing, please tell me :-)

Comment: You should try `$scope.item = { Store: ... }` item is not yet an object, you must create it first and then set the store property.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that the object will be created at the scope automatically. Anyway, I also think there is something wrong with the ng-options, logically it should be 'ng-options="item.Store.storeName for item.Store in item.Stores"' but thats not working too...

Comment: I think the same goes for your list: `$scope.items = { stores: [ ... ] };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WoVhQCf5bLj3PWEy37ym?p=preview) which contains the modifications mentionned in the comments of the OP.

```
$scope.items = {
    stores: [
      {id : 1, name : 'Spar' },      
      {id : 2, name : 'Billa' },
      {id : 3, name : 'Merkur' }, 
    ]
};

$scope.item = {
    store: $scope.items.stores[1]
}
```