# How to add empty option in select in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a select box.

When no value is selected, I have the empty option `--`. It's OK !

Once an option is selected, the empty option disappears.

But I would like that it is always there to have the opportunity to choose `--`.

Is it possible ?

```
<select ng-model="project" ng-options="act.id as act.name for act in actors"></select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114096/angularjs-alway-blank-element-in-select-tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please see here:http://plnkr.co/edit/SWpRZA1dafNNva70z6KE?p=preview

```
<select ng-model="project" ng-options="act.id as act.name for act in actors">
    <option value="">--<option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to store in the model `item.color`

Comment: That was just sample I've update plukr for you http://plnkr.co/edit/SWpRZA1dafNNva70z6KE?p=preview

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

ng-options gets priority when any option is selected from .

As per the standard html  can contain . Thus the mentioned option gets priority as the selection is null.

And in view, html priority is higher, thus always  value is seen unless the ng-option value already selected from controller.